# CashCode Bill2Bill communication error on linux

Tags: linux, serial-port

We are facing the same problem as described here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866654/communicating-with-cashcode-bill-acceptor-in-linux/31262611#31262611) with Bill2Bill on linux system. Everything works on Windows, but on linux after sending POLL command {0x02, 0x01, 0x06, 0x33, 0x62, 0x34} we can't read any data from serial port. Device is stucked and do not respond.
We've already tried solution posted in that topic but with no luck. 
Is there any possibility that bytes wrote to serial port on linux are somehow changed and bill2bill gets modified data or structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out you just have to send several poll commands on linux before you get first answer.